# Jenkins: Changing branch that triggers build

Tags: jenkins

I have inherited a Jenkins system. When there is a commit to master a build is triggered, but I do not see what causes that. GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling is checked, but there are no hooks defined in github. But when there is a commit I see this in the Jenkins log:

```
Last GitHub Push
Started on Aug 13, 2019 6:58:57 PM
Started by event from 140.82.115.69 ⇒ http://xxxx:8081/github-webhook/ on Tue Aug 13 18:58:57 EDT 2019
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision ca6af2965f56c6c2b2b63c596d899abd83a4f6b4 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h git@github.com:xxxx/ia.git # timeout=10
Found 20 remote heads on git@github.com:xxxx/ia.git
Done. Took 0.37 sec
changes
```

I want to change this so a commit to a different branch triggers a build. I did change the branch speficier in the Source Code Management section of the project's config, but when that branch changes no build is triggered.

I do see an updated message in the last git hub push log, but it only references master and says no change.

What do I need to change to do this?

Comment: Your jenkins build configuration may have a 'Branch Specifier' configured.

Comment: There is a branch specifier and I did change it. But it does not get notified by git when that branch changes, only when master changes.

Comment: A few other possibilities to look into:
- Your SCM config may specify a Refspec.
- 'Poll SCM' settings may define a branch, even if configured not to poll.
It seems odd that github has no hooks defined but you're getting a `github-webhook` call that seems to originate from github.

Comment: There is no refspec. There is nothing in the Poll SCM section. Yes, I think it must be missing something as it is clearly getting a message from git but I see nothing there in the webhooks section. And I am the repo owner.